# Laravel Blade - add variable inside javascript confirmation

Tags: laravel

i want the javascript confirmation to include the variable name $button_label. Which means that it should have a confirmation of "Save record ?" or "Update record ?".

I'm having a hard time doing it.

Any thoughts?

```
@php $button_label = Route::current()->getName() == 'maintenance.state.edit' ? 'Update record' : 'Save record' ; @endphp
{!! Form::submit($button_label, ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg', 'onclick' => 'return confirm("Proceed ?")']) !!}
```

Comment: Did you used the same action for the update and save? Provide your controller code also.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
"return confirm('{$button_label} ?')"
```

Also read [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), if you want to learn why i changed the positions of single and double quotes.

Comment: ill try this later when i got home because it's a side project that im working on. thank you for your time.

Comment: can you give me information about usage of the single bracket? can you point me to any links.

Comment: I think you can find useful infos on the same link.